# Omission of articles

Tags: articles

Is there a rule for omission of articles in case of enumeration or comparison? 
For example, in the following sentence there is no article before “saving scheme”:

> Some people believe that it is best to save money, for example **in a bank or saving scheme**. (From “IELTS band 9 essays”)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, no rules.

You can let the indefinite article be “distributed” such that it applies to both objects on either side the conjunction; for example:

> ...in a bank or saving scheme.
>   ...in a sentence or question. 
>   ...on a car or truck.

or you can choose to repeat the article in front of each object:

> ...in a bank or **a** saving scheme.
>   ...in a sentence or **s** question.
>   ...on a car or **a** truck.

This is usually a stylistic choice, not a grammatical one.

Comment: There's *one* rule (though still stylistic more than grammatical), which is to be *consistent* about whether or not an article is distributed at any given level; "a bank, building society, or a saving scheme" feels wrong, but "a bank, building society, or saving scheme" and "a bank, a building society, or a saving scheme" are both fine.

Comment: @Darael - That is an insightful remark, a useful clarification, and a helpful comment. :-)